# Python threading: interpreter shutdown exception

Tags: python, multithreading, emulation

I'm writing an emulator for a vintage computer system in Python, and I'm having some trouble with an exception thrown when trying to "restart" the emulator core thread after coming out of a halt condition.  The "run processor" method, part of a larger class looks something like this:

```
def run_processor(self):
    processor = self

    class processor_thread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.daemon = True

        def run(self):
            while processor.running:
               #main loop for instruction fetch and decode is here   

    self.processor_thread = processor_thread()
    self.running = True   
    self.processor_thread.start()
```

I have a main function where I load a memory image into the processor, set the program counter, and run a test program on the emulator.  This outputs some stuff to the console, and eventually the processor's "HLT" instruction sets "processor.running" to False, terminating processor_thread.

This works OK, but where I'm running in to trouble is a test of restarting the processor by calling run_processor a second time:

```
processor = Processor(memory, scheduler, interrupts, teleprinter)
processor.program_counter = 128
processor.run_processor()
while processor.processor_thread.isAlive():
    pass
processor.program_counter = 128
processor.run_processor()
```

The first instance runs fine, but when the run_processor method is called a second time I get the following error:

> Exception in thread Thread-3 (most likely raised during interpreter
>   shutdown)

How can I rectify this? Thanks.

EDIT: I broke the code down to its bare essentials and found it actually works OK.  I didn't notice that my HALT method was actually written in such a way that it shut down all the processor peripheral threads, *including* the thread that runs the teleprinter emulator.  Without the teleprinter to output to it looks like the emulator core crashed on the second test.

Here's the test case:

```
import threading
import time

class Processor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = False

    def halt_processor(self):
        self.running = False

    def run_processor(self):
        processor = self

        class processor_thread(threading.Thread):
            def __init__(self):
                threading.Thread.__init__(self)
                self.daemon = True

            def run(self):
                while processor.running:
                   #main loop for instruction fetch and decode is here   
                   print "Hello, I am the main loop doing my thing 1"
                   time.sleep(1)
                   print "Hello, I am the main loop doing my thing 2"
                   time.sleep(1)
                   print "I will halt now."
                   processor.halt_processor()

        self.processor_thread = processor_thread()
        self.running = True   
        self.processor_thread.start()

def test1():
    processor = Processor()
    processor.run_processor()

def test2():
    processor = Processor()
    processor.run_processor()
    while processor.processor_thread.isAlive():
        pass
    processor.run_processor()

def main():
     test2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Works OK.

Comment: @Wessie But after the first thread has terminated, am I not creating a new thread in the line "self.processor_thread = processor_thread()" during the second call to "processor.run_processor()"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I failed to read your code correctly. Disregard that first comment.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you can ignore this error. If your program works, any errors during shutdown could be ignored. I'm fully with you that this isn't the way things should be and that a clean solution is called for.

What I think is missing is the call to `thread.join()`. You are currently busy-waiting for the thread to return false from `isAlive()` (which should be `is_alive()`, btw), using `join()` is cleaner and shorter.

BTW: There is no need to derive from the `Thread` class, which makes the code a bit shorter. I personally find it clearer, too, because the Python object is just a handle to the thread and not the thread itself.

Comment: Thank you, I will give your suggestions a try as well.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, the main thread ends just after starting again the Processor thread.
Have you tried to put a `while` after starting it?

P.S.: Also, some nice working code would make debugging much easier for those that want to help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll try to get a runnable program that demonstrates the problem posted.